# У меня выходит ошибка module 'rsa' has no attribute 'newkeys'

Tags: python, rsa

Вот код:

```
import rsa
pubkey, privkey = rsa.newkeys(512) # Генерируем 2 ключа
mess = 'Hello, Codeby!'
cipher = rsa.encrypt(mess, pubkey) # Шифруем print(cipher)
mess = rsa.decrypt(crypto, privkey) # Расшифровываем print(mess)
```

Вот ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/user.DESKTOP-N6AQFSN/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/rsa4.py", line 2, in pubkey, privkey = rsa.newkeys(512) # Генерируем 2 ключа AttributeError: module 'rsa' has no attribute 'newkeys'

В чем может быть проблема?

Библиотеку RSA установил. pip install rsa

Comment: Да в тексте ошибки вроде четко написано, в чем проблема.

Comment: @Эникейщик А в [документации](https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/usage.html#generating-keys) приведен прям такой же пример кода.

Comment: @Jazzis Значит, документация устарела. Или же установлена не так версия модуля. Или вы думаете, что текст ошибки врет??

Comment: @Эникейщик Сам не пробовал, так что пока ещё ничего не думаю :) А ошибке верю, что-то тут не чисто.

Comment: @Jazzis А где вы документацию нашли? У меня только исходники на гитхабе открываются, а ссылка на документацию не работает.

Comment: `pip install rsa` прям загуглил, выдало https://pypi.org/project/rsa/. Не обратил внимания на chagelog (сразу в доку полез), а там сказано что для 3.4 эти модули считаются устаревшими.

Comment: Похоже, что проблема в том, что питон версии 3.8. На 3.5 все работает.

Comment: На 3.7, кстати, тоже всё пучком.

Comment: @Jazzis "А в документации" -  у меня эта страница не открывается :/ Я про нее и говорил. Наверное, прокси блокирует.